# C++ Dynamic Memory Allocation - char*

Tags: c++, c, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having a problem understanding a part of dynamic memory allocation in C++.

I know its standard practice to do something like this to avoid memory leak:

```
double* pvalue  = NULL; // Pointer initialized with null
pvalue  = new double;   // Request memory for the variable
*pvalue = 29494.99;  
delete pvalue;
```

However, I've seen lots of source code like this and `delete` was never used there to free up memory:

```
char* text = "something";
```

So the question is simple: should I use `delete` EVERY time I no longer need a char pointer (or ANY other)? Or are there some exceptions?

I've read alot and I'm only getting more confused so I hope somebody can help me.

---

**EDIT**:

Thank you for explanation. Finally I understand and I can make changes to my source code without worrying!

Comment: You should have a `delete` for each `new` if you want to clean everything up. `char* text = "something";` is not doing dynamic memory allocation. There is no `new`.

Comment: string literals were made a bit of a special case back in C for convenience reasons afaik.

Comment: Instead of worrying about this, you should never need to use `delete` except in very special cases. Use `std::string` and other containers and smart pointers and RAII classes that manage the resource on their own.

Comment: @chris Ok thank you. Ill try to convert to string wherever I can. Finally I can sleep well!

Comment: I seem to be in the minority in thinking that students should learn to handle pointers and arrays before moving up to advanced containers like strings.

Comment: @SzloseProgramming you should not write thank you or something like that in your question. Accept the answer if it solves your problem or comment .

Comment: @Beta, and have 3/4 of your students quit C++ and go to Java.  Also, I don't see what is advanced about `std::string`.  Even Stroustrup recommends introducing C++ this way (use `std::string` from the start).

Comment: Pointers and arrays are far more advanced than `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @Beta: Nonsense. First teach `vector`, `array`, `string`, non-owning pointers. Later, as they progress, teach advanced concepts like manually handling dynamic allocations and raw arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `delete` everything you create with `new`, and nothing else.

```
char* text = "something";
```

This does not create something with `new`, so you shouldn't `delete` it.

In fact, that statement doesn't create *anything* (apart from a pointer) - it sets `text` to point to a string that was created when your program started.